# How do I create a highlight on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, css

On [my page](http://www.urlgone.com/d7ccf8/), if i mouseover a state, the hyperlink on the right changes to a hover style.  Can someone suggest how I might make the opposite happen.. when I hover one of the hyperlinks on the right, the state is highlighted (as when I hover over the state itself)?

Comment: You just need do the opposite way.

Comment: @Jeff could you kindly update your post to contain the code applicable to the mouseover and mouseout. Also the HTML source for the image map and a sample of the HTML for the links would be nice. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Question is now useless to future readers without the code.  Good job OP!

Answer (score 1):

Very simply using jQuery's .trigger();

as an example: `$('#A0').trigger('mouseover');` would highlight the first element in the map (Washington).

So `<a class="staffs staff-A0" href="#">Washington</a>` you could add this to the mouseover event:

```
var map_element_id = '#' + this.className.split('-')[1];
$(map_element_id).trigger('mouseover');
```

and of course onmouseout needs to be handled as well. 
There are many ways to handle the assignment of the map_element_id variable. I do suggest you assign a separate attribute to store this rather than a classname (maybe data-map-id?). Splitting on '-' works with this example, but imagine you add more class names to the element that contain '-' this would fail.

Comment: the map ID is 'A0' not 'starff-A0'

Comment: Oh... now I get it, My bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of the map area and trigger the mouseover event.

```
$('.staff').mouseover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("class").split("-")[1];
    $("#"+id).trigger('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: why wrap all of `this` with jQuery when using the native methods is easier and faster. this.className.split('-')[0]; does in one line what you do in two with less performance (not that it would matter in this example). Some times we're too quick to wrap things up in a $()

Comment: @rlemon, you are right, but in this case its near neglegeable

Comment: but learning good practices is never negligible :P this is how good coders get into bad habits.